# flatpickr first day of week Monday and shorthandcurrentMonth

Tags: flatpickr

I have started to use flatpickr on a form and it's working but want to add couple of options to it. I want to add the firstDayOfWeek so that Monday is the first day of the week and then want to shorthandCurrentMonth so it shows Jun instead of June

I know the option code I have is sort of working as dateFormat: "d-m-Y", works if I change the date format and it shows the date format I alter in the dateFormat line but unsure why the firstDayofWeek and shorthandCurrentMonth is not working, below is the code I have

```
<script>
 var example = flatpickr("#flatpickr", {    
 // A string of characters which are used to define how the date will be displayed in the input box. 
 dateFormat: "d-m-Y",
 // Show the month using the shorthand version.
shorthandCurrentMonth: true,
"locale": {
    "firstDayOfWeek": 1 // start week on Monday
}
});    
</script>
```

Update: Just got it working by using the cdn files as mentioned on https://www.cssscript.com/flat-style...ker-flatpickr/ as was originally using the code from them files but might be conflicting with something the way I did it originally or coding was possibly missing